# How can I calculate and plot average wavelet coherency across periods using R WaveletComp package?

Tags: r, wavelet

I am calculating wavelet coherency using the R package WaveletComp v. 1.1. I know I can plot the average coherency for each scale/period (averaging across time) using `wc.avg()` but I would also like to plot the averaged coherency at each time (averaging coherency across periods/scales). I don't find a specific function to do that within the package but would appreciate some help on how to calculate those averages using the output from the `analyze.coherency()` function.

The output data from the function `analyze.coherency()`  is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eow3u3xr4pcjki2/wc_output.txt?dl=0) and can be opened using `dget()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: Thanks, I added link to sample data.